# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cropbox' 2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, cropperjs, shrine

I asked question  [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cropbox'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871451/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-cropbox)
But I didn't get an answer, so I have to focus on more specific issues and searching in StackOverflow,

So that I get three problem

1  rails doesn't load cropbox.js

2  clopbox.js couldn't  export cropbox function

3  fileUplod.js couldn't import cropbox function

this is the result  what the as one of  the above problem

part of application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'cropbox' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'fileUpload'%> #Here is deleted
```

Intentionally, I don't compile fileUpload
as a result, rails could load clopbox.js
So, I narrow down 2 problem

someone would you like to tell me these problems?

Environment:

**Rails 6.0.2** **Ruby 2.5.3**

app/javascript/packs/fileUpload.js:

```
import clopbox from './packs/cropbox' **#Here is problem **



 uppy.on('upload-success', (file, response) => {
// retrieve uploaded file data
const uploadedFileData = response.body['data']

// set hidden field value to the uploaded file data so that it's submitted
// with the form as the attachment
hiddenInput.value = JSON.stringify(uploadedFileData)

cropbox(imagePreview, response.uploadURL, {
  onCrop(detail) {
    let fileData = JSON.parse(hiddenInput.value)
    fileData['metadata']['crop'] = detail
    hiddenInput.value = JSON.stringify(fileData)
  }
})
})
```

webpacker.yml:

```
  # Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

 default: &default
 source_path: app/javascript
 source_entry_path: packs
 public_root_path: public
 public_output_path: packs
 cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
 check_yarn_integrity: false
 webpack_compile_output: true

# Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
# ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
resolved_paths: []

# Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
cache_manifest: false

# Extract and emit a css file
extract_css: false

static_assets_extensions:
  - .jpg
  - .jpeg
  - .png
  - .gif
  - .tiff
  - .ico
  - .svg
  - .eot
  - .otf
  - .ttf
  - .woff
  - .woff2

extensions:
  - .mjs
  - .js
  - .sass
  - .scss
  - .css
  - .module.sass
  - .module.scss
  - .module.css
  - .png
  - .svg
  - .gif
  - .jpeg
  - .jpg

development:
 <<: *default
  compile: true

# Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, 
and 
node_modules
check_yarn_integrity: true

# Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
  https: false
  host: localhost
  port: 3035
  public: localhost:3035
  hmr: false
  # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
  inline: true
  overlay: true
  compress: true
  disable_host_check: true
  use_local_ip: false
  quiet: false
  pretty: false
  headers:
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  watch_options:
  ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

# Compile test packs to a separate directory
public_output_path: packs-test

production:
<<: *default

# Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for 
performance.
compile: false

 # Extract and emit a css file
 extract_css: true

 # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

app/javascript/packs/cropbox.js:

```
 import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css'

import Cropper from 'cropperjs'

function cropbox(image, url, { onCrop }) {
image.src = url

new Cropper(image, {
 aspectRatio: 1,
 viewMode: 1,
 guides: false,
 autoCropArea: 1.0,
 background: false,
 zoomable: false,
 crop: event => onCrop(event.detail)
 })
 }

export default cropbox
```

form.html.erb

```
  <%= form_with model: @blog_form , url: user_blogs_path ,local: true do |f| 
  %>

  <div class="field">
  <%  f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%  f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field ">
   <%  f.label :user_id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
   </div>

   <div class ="field form-group">
   <%= f.fields_for  :photos, Photo.new do |photos_fileds|  %>

   <%= photos_fileds.label :image , class: "form-control" %>
   <%= photos_fileds.hidden_field :image,  class: "upload-data", value: 
   photos_fileds.object.cached_image_data %>
   <%= photos_fileds.file_field  :image , class: "form-control  ", id: 
   "select- 
   files"%><br/>
   <div class="image-preview">
    <img id="image" src="<%= photos_fileds.object.image_url(:medium) %>" 
     height="300" class="rounded"  >
    </div>

    <% end %>

    </div>

    <%= f.submit "create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

log:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/fileUpload.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './packs/cropbox' in 
'/home/master/prot/prottype2/app/javascript/packs'
@ ./app/javascript/packs/fileUpload.js 1:0-38

[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 39733ms (Views: 39715.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I could load the cropbox,
 I have no idea what this solution is the right solution
But I'm going to write answers for just in case

I added code in webpacker.yml  which is

```
resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/packs']
```